# How can I understand this transformation of the Black Scholes equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transformation, boundary-value-problem

I have a problem concerning the transformation of a PDE. (It is actually a linear complementarity problem for American option, however my problem only concerns the underlying mathematics/PDE).

For a function $V(S,t)$, $t \in [0,T]$ and $S \geq 0$, I consider the problem (with $r,\delta > 0$)
$$
(V - V(S,T))\left(V_t + \frac{\sigma^2}2 S^2V_{SS}+(r-\delta)SV_S -rV\right) = 0, \\
V - V(S,T) \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad -\left(V_t + \frac{\sigma^2}2 S^2V_{SS}+(r-\delta)SV_S -rV\right) \geq 0
$$
with boundary and final conditions given as follows:
$$
V(0,t) = K, \quad \lim_{S \to \infty}V(S,t) = 0, \quad V(S,T) = (K - S)^+.
$$

Now, my problem: One can make the transformation
$$
x = \log(K/S), \quad \tau = \frac{\sigma^2}2(T-t)
$$
and define with $k_\delta = \frac{2(r-\delta)}{\sigma^2}$,
$$
u(x,\tau) = \exp\left(\frac12 (k_\delta-1)x+\frac14(k_\delta-1)^2\tau+k_0\tau)\right)\frac{V(S,t)}K.
$$
Then the above PDE (when set equal to 0) is transformed into the nice equation $u_\tau = u_{xx}$.
However, then in my lecture notes, the function $f$ is defined as follows
$$
f(x,\tau) = \exp\left(\frac12 (k_\delta-1)x+\frac14(k_\delta-1)^2\tau+k_0\tau)\right)\frac{V(Ke^x,T)}K
$$
and it is claimed that the above term $(V - V(S,T))$ turns into $(u - f)$. Obviously $V$ turns into $u$, but how can $V(S,T)$ (a function not depending on time, not on $t$ or $\tau$) turn into $f$, which clearly depends on time (in the form of $\tau$)?
Additionally, it is claimed that the second boundary condition is now given by
$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty}(u(x,\tau) - f(x,\tau)) = 0,
$$
where I am also confused about the use of the function $f$.

Can someone explain to me, what the idea behind the function $f$ is or should it maybe done differently? How can I understand the transformation of the transformed boundary condition?

Thanks in advance!